# string matching for exact value in a column when a string as a comma in R

Tags: r, dataframe, grepl

I would like to find the exact matches for a given query (the example below is querying for 'ABC'.  However I want all the rows with ABC exactly or if it separated by a comma.  Which means I would like the desired output below.

**Sample Data:**

```
query = c('ABC')

col1 = c("ABC", "DEF", "ABCDE", "DAC", "CBA,ABC,LMN1")
col2 = c("DEF", "EQ", "AC", "DE,ABC", "QSX")
col3 = c(12, 30, NA, 0, 54)
df = data.frame(col1, col2, col3)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
            col1      col2     col3
1            ABC       DEF       12
4            DAC    DE,ABC        0
5   CBA,ABC,LMN1       QSX       54
```

I've tried to use `grepl` but I'm getting the following (see row labeled 3).

```
df[with(df, grepl(query, col1)|grepl(query, col2)),]
```

**My Output (not desired):**

```
            col1      col2     col3
1            ABC       DEF       12
3          ABCDE        AC       NA
4            DAC    DE,ABC        0
5   CBA,ABC,LMN1       QSX       54
```

What's the best way of ensuring I get the rows I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a word boundary in 'query'.  Loop through the columns, apply the `grepl`, `Reduce` it to a single logical `vector` with `|`, use that to subset the rows

```
queryN <- paste0("\\b", query, "\\b")
df[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[1:2], grepl, pattern = queryN)),]
#           col1   col2 col3
#1          ABC    DEF   12
#4          DAC DE,ABC    0
#5 CBA,ABC,LMN1    QSX   54
```

---

Or using the OP's method

```
df[with(df, grepl(queryN, col1)|grepl(queryN, col2)),]
```